# What happens to locks on objects passed to other threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I'm not quite sure how to word this, so I'll just paste my code and ask the question:

```
private void remoteAction_JobStatusUpdated(JobStatus status) {
    lock (status) {
        status.LastUpdatedTime = DateTime.Now;
        doForEachClient(c => c.OnJobStatusUpdated(status));
        OnJobStatusUpdated(status);
    }
}

private void doForEachClient(Action<IRemoteClient> task) {
    lock (clients) {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<RemoteClientId, IRemoteClient> entry in clients) {
            IRemoteClient clientProxy = entry.Value;
            RemoteClientId clientId = entry.Key;
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate {
                try {
                    task(clientProxy);
#pragma warning disable 168
                } catch (CommunicationException ex) {
#pragma warning restore 168
                    RemoveClient(clientId);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Assume that any other code which modifies the `status` object will acquire a lock on it first.

Since the `status` object is passed all the way through to multiple `ThreadPool` threads, and the call to `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` will complete before the actual tasks complete, am I ensuring that the same `status` object gets sent to all clients?

Put another way, when does the `lock (status)` statement "expire" or cause its lock to be released?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Locks don't *expire*. When a thread tries to pass the `lock` statement it can only do it if no other thread is executing inside a `lock` block having a lock on that particular object instance used in the `lock` statemement.

In your case it seems that you have a main thread executing. It will lock both the `status` and the `clients` instances before it spins of new tasks that are executed on seperate threads. If any code in the new threads want to acquire a lock on either `status` or `clients` it will have to wait until the main thread has released both locks by leaving both `lock` blocks. That happens when `remoteAction_JobStatusUpdated` returns.

You pass the `status` object to each worker thread and they are all free to do whatever they want to do with that object. The statement `lock (status)` in no way protects the `status` instance. However, if any of the threads tries to execute `lock (status)` they will block until the main thread releases the lock.

Using two separate object instances to lock can lead to deadlock. Assume one thread executes the following code:

```
lock (status) {
  ...
  lock (clients) {
    ...
  }
```

}

Another thread executes the following code where the locks are acquired in the reverse sequence:

```
lock (clients) {
  ...
  lock (status) {
    ...
  }
```

}

If the first thread manages to get the status first and the second the clients lock first they are deadlocked and both threads will no longer run.

In general I would advice you to encapsulate your shared state in a separate class and make access to it thread safe:

```
class State {

  readonly Object locker = new Object();

  public void ModifyState() {
    lock (this.locker) {
      ...
    }
  }

  public String AccessState() {
    lock (this.locker) {
      ...
      return ...
    }
  }

}
```

You can also mark you methods with the [[MethodImpl(MethodImpl.Synchronized)]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimplattribute.aspx) attribute, but it has its pitfalls as it will surround the method with a `lock (this)` which in general isn't recommended.

If you want to better understand what is going on behind the scenes of the `lock` statement you can read the [Safe Thread Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188793.aspx) article in MSDN Magazine.

Comment: Edited the question to hopefully clarify my wording.  I forgot to say that any other code which modifies my `status` object will acquire a lock on it first.  Anyway that answers my question, thanks.

Comment: A question, though:  you say "you can't pass locks on to other threads."  But as a contrived example, say I did `lock(someObject) { Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(doSomething)); t.Start(); t.Join(); }` - then the lock would effectively be passed on to my other thread since it would be held the whole time that thread was running, right?

Comment: @jnylen: I've removed the text you are quoting from my answer since it wasn't very meaningful. With regard to your example: The answer is yes as long as the new thread doesn't try to `lock (someObject)`. Otherwise you have a deadlock where both threads are blocked waiting for the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

The locks certainly don't "expire" on their own, the lock will be valid until the closing brace of the lock(..){} statement.

Comment: "Expire" was a bad choice of words.